# What happened with 10k tools?

Tags: support, faq, 10k-tools

Back when I *just* got my reputation over 10k, my tools used to show me various things, for example the [automatic flag raised for duplicate answers](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3279/16495), which I don't see anymore.

Was it a deliberate change, was I banned, or is there a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no flag queue for 10K users any more; it was removed on April 2014.

For more details, see [Let's get rid of the 10K flag queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue). In short, flags are now handled differently and faster, and there is not anymore need of 10K tools, which were requiring more efforts from 10K users to use it, and from the developers to fix their bugs and keep it aligned with the diamond moderator's tools from which they were derived.